# Why is the ticker and date different

Tags: python, pandas, date

Here is my early attempts in using Python. I am getting stock data from Yahoo but I can see that the ticker, date column headers are lower than the high low open close.

I am definitely missing something. What is it?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime
import pandas_datareader as pdr


py.init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

# we download the stock prices for each ticker and then we do a mapping between data and name of the ticker
def get(tickers, startdate, enddate):
  def data(ticker):
    return (pdr.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start=startdate, end=enddate))
  datas = map (data, tickers)
  return(pd.concat(datas, keys=tickers, names=['ticker', 'date']))

# Define the stocks to download. We'll download of Apple, Microsoft and the S&P500 index.
tickers = ['AAPL','IBM']

# We would like all available data from 01/01/2000 until 31/12/2018.
start_date = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 31)

all_data = get(tickers, start_date, end_date)
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrLHW.png)

Answer (score 0):

This dataframe uses a hierarchical index. `ticker` and `date` aren't columns, but are both part of the index. This means the rows are grouped firstly by ticker and then by date.

For more information on hierarchical indexes check out the Pandas [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html)